# SQL date correction, through trigger or procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have entered some date which had a date column, the date format was not correct, now if I entered them again it will take months to fix, any idea if I can fix it trough some trigger, for example. the date entered in the data is 5/9/2012 but the actual date was 9/5/2012. any idea????

I just made a trigger is it safe?? I want it effect only one row, not all, am I correct in logic?

```
  GO
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnReceiptUpdate]
    ON  [dbo].[paymentReceipt]
    AFTER UPDATE 
    AS 
    BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare   @correctdate VARCHAR(19);
   Declare   @receiptNo VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @customerID NCHAR(50)
SET @customerID= (SELECT customerID FROM inserted)
 set @correctdate =  (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),paymentDate,103) FROM inserted)   
  set @receiptNo =  (SELECT receiptNo FROM inserted)      
   BEGIN

   UPDATE Paymentreceipt
       SET paymentDate = @correctdate 
    WHERE customerID = @customerID and receiptNo=@receiptNo  
   END
 END'
```

Comment: how to distinguish right from wrong entries?

Comment: what is your date column type?
Is it in date format or nvarchar?

Comment: if if date is greater then 12 it means its entered correctly, all other dates which are not greater then 12 should be treated wrong dates. because month. and also I will check the dates myself but I want a trigger which updates date correctly which I edit selected record.  I have tried to edit them manuauly so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting Date time format in SQL check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

If you problem is that you need to update all records and switch the date with the month

For example, the output of the next 2 queries

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),101)
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),103)
```

will be

> ```
> 06/02/2013
> 02/06/2013
> ```

So your query should look like this

```
Update MyTable
Set myDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),101)
```

Trigger is good when you can't\dont want to change the application code, so you will "fix" it yourself in the DB. This is not good practice and you should use it when there is no other option since the code changes here is simple

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateTimeEntry
ON dbo.TimeEntry
AFTER UPDATE
AS
 ... place your code here
```

Comment: you just need to update the update query , so it will work on all rows in table `insert`